# How to use the mexgauss from the retimes package with cells that have NA

Tags: r, database, function, na

I keep on getting this error when I try to run mexgauss (From the retimes package)
here is a sample of the data.

`    data1$None
     [1] 1256 1292 1299 1268 1551 1362 1462 1317 1354 1429 1552
     [12] 1291 1355 1347 1228 1424 1769 1352 1268 1428   NA   NA
     [23]   NA   NA   NA

> mexgauss(data1$None)
>        Error in if (k[3] > 0) start[3] <- (k[3]/2)^(1/3) else start[3] <- 0.8 *  : 
>        missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I want to run this command on this data set for my thesis. I cannot figure out what this error is. Further I am not sure how to take all the NA's and tell R that they are false.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much. It would mean the world to me.

Comment: a few options, if the function has a `na.rm` argument use that. Change the NA before running the function using `data1$None[data1$None == NA] = 0` or use `tryCatch(mexgauss(data1$None), error =function(e) 0)` If you can't have 0 replaced for NA then I'm not sure...

Comment: Neither of these work. Thank you though!

Comment: I have been using the command like this to manually exclude rows with NA.    <mexgauss(data1$None[1:24])

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at this, mexgauss() appears to break and generate that cryptic message when there are NA in the data the ex-Gaussian parameters are being estimated on. The solution is simply to omit NAs from the vector fed into mexgauss() by wrapping said vector in na.omit(). See below for full example.

```
library(retimes)

# make mock datasets
  x1 <- 1:10
  x2 <- c(1:9, NA)

# try to run mexguass()
  mexgauss(x1) # no missing data: it works fine
  mexgauss(x2) # returns cryptic error OP mentioned

# solution: wrap data with NA in na.omit
  mexgauss(na.omit(x2)) # works fine
```